# Add claims when creating a new user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

I am creating a new User using ASP.NET Core Identity as follows:

```
new User {
  Email = "john@company.com",
  Name = "John"
}

await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "password");
```

I need to add a Claims when creating the user. I tried:

```
new User {
  Email = "john@company.com",
  Name = "John",
  Claims = new List<Claim> { /* Claims to be added */ }  
}
```

But Claims property is read only.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39556785/5426333

Comment: I am not looking to save data in the authentication cookie. I am looking to saving adding claims to the user and save it to the database

Comment: I didn't test it but as far as i understand from comments claims are saved in database.

Comment: await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("your-claim", "your-value"));

Comment: @aguafrommars Yes, that is right ... Can you add an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `UserManager<YourUser>.AddClaimAsync` method to add a claims to your user

```
var user = new User {
  Email = "john@company.com",
  Name = "John"
}

await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "password");

await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("your-claim", "your-value"));
```

Or add claims to the user `Claims` collection

```
var user = new User {
  Email = "john@company.com",
  Name = "John"
}

user.Claims.Add(new IdentityUserClaim<string> 
{ 
    ClaimType="your-type", 
    ClaimValue="your-value" 
});

await userManager.CreateAsync(user);
```